# Joining sql table and R dataframe in query

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, sqldf

I have question that is there any way to join or to use R dataframe in environment in sql query or another tables in data wharehouse, i know there is some question which use R variable in sql, but it is only for vector, or one column of dataframe, I found one example using sqldf function but it is not working, I am not sure even it is possible or not, I know it sound really crazy but it is really interesting for me and if it is possible, it would be very useful.

This is my simple code, lets say we have df dataframe, and I have example table in postgre db

```
# R data frame
df <- data.frame(ID = "Apt", Name = "2023-01-01")

# Join the R data frame and PostgreSQL table using SQL syntax
result <- sqldf('SELECT * FROM csa."example" as aa INNER JOIN df ON df.ID = aa.client_name',
                drv = "PostgreSQL", connection = con)
```

```
query <- sprintf('SELECT * FROM csa."example" as aa INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM df) as bb ON bb.ID = aa.client_name', df)

result <- sqldf(query, drv = "PostgreSQL", connection = con)

# Display the result
print(result)
```

Comment: (I removed the [tag:rstudio] tag, this question seems to be about R not the IDE you're using. If this behaves different in simple-R than it does within the RStudio editor, my apologies, please help me to see where that happens.)

Comment: I _suspect_ (though perhaps the package author will correct me) that `sqldf` using a postgres engine is going to use a distinct namespace so that there is no inadvertent over-writing or ambiguity.

Comment: You can remove, I believe it is not about IDE as well, but I didnot exactly get what you meant in second comment

Comment: What I mean about "namespace" is that while it may be using the postgres engine, I don't know that you have access to the other tables in whichever schema is being used, that's all.

Comment: Yeah, I have. firstly I have already tried with vertica, oracle as well, but didnot work, I think, it is not possible even